# ZonedDateTime timezone inconsistency issue?

Tags: java, java-8, date

I need to write one function which will create the future installments for the invoice. Below is the function which creates the list of future installment dates :-

```
public List<Date> getInstallmentDates(Invoice objectWithInvoiceDateField, int noOfInstallments, String instFreq)
{
    //objectWithInvoiceDateField.getInvoiceDate this will return java.util.Date instance
    ZonedDateTime invoiceDate = objectWithInvoiceDateField.getInvoiceDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime firstInstallment = ZonedDateTime.of( invoiceDate.getYear(), invoiceDate.getMonthValue() , invoiceDate.getDayOfMonth() , 0 , 0 , 0, 0 , ZoneId.systemDefault());
    List<Date> installmentDates = new ArrayList();
    installmentDates.add(Date.from(firstInstallment.toInstant()));//First Installment
    /*Code for the subsequent installments*/
    for (int i = 1; i < noOfInstallments; i++) {
        ZonedDateTime subsequentInstallments = null;
        if(instFreq.equalsIgnoreCase("Quarterly")) {
            subsequentInstallments = firstInstallment.plusMonths(3*i);
        }
        else if(instFreq.equalsIgnoreCase("Semi-annual")){
            subsequentInstallments = firstInstallment.plusMonths(6*i);
        }
        else
            subsequentInstallments = firstInstallment.plusMonths(i);
        installmentDates.add(Date.from(subsequentInstallments.toInstant()));
    }
    return installmentDates;
}
```

This works as expected except for the last iteration. Below is the output if I run this method from main method for

> getInstallmentDates(invoice, 5, "Monthly");

```
Thu Jul 30 00:00:00 EDT 2020
Sun Aug 30 00:00:00 EDT 2020
Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 EDT 2020
Fri Oct 30 00:00:00 EDT 2020
Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 ***EST*** 2020
```

Can some one please help me understand why the timezone for last instance is changed to EST ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) stops on the first Sunday of November, and Eastern Standard Time (EST) begins. Anything wrong with that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone#Daylight_saving_time

Comment: Why are you using "time" at all, the method seems to call for dates to be returned so do much of the same thing but with "LocalDate" instead

Comment: @Sweeper is right, just my 5 cents regarding ZoneId.systemDefault()). 
I would suggest you to use only time as UTC and in the end could format it in any timezone for presentation.

Comment: Is it a requirement for the method to return `List<Date>`? IMO, it should return `List<LocalDate>`, or `List<YearMonth>` even.

Comment: @Sweeper : Yes.

Comment: Never use `Date` or `Calendar` classes. These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably because you have used the timezone to be ZoneId.systemDefault(), and your system defaults to a timezone that honours daylight saving time. Assuming EDT is Eastern Daylight Time and EST is Eastern Standard Time, in 2020 the end of daylight saving happens on 1 November and therefore the timezone name changes.